# Use an office .ODC connection in VB.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, odbc

This is the connection string used within excel, I was wondering if there was any way to connect to this database using vb.net to bring back data via SQL.

In other words how can I use this connection string in my web application

```
<odc:OfficeDataConnection
  xmlns:odc="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:odc"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <odc:Connection odc:Type="OLEDB">
   <odc:ConnectionString>Provider=MSOLAP.4;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=[databasename];Data Source=[servername];MDX Compatibility=1;Safety Options=2;MDX Missing Member Mode=Error</odc:ConnectionString>
   <odc:CommandType>Cube</odc:CommandType>
   <odc:CommandText>PnL</odc:CommandText>
  </odc:Connection>
 </odc:OfficeDataConnection>
```

I have tried this below, but it doesn't seem to work, any ideas?

```
    Dim Conn As OdbcConnection = New OdbcConnection("DProvider=MSOLAP.4;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True; " _
       & " Initial Catalog=[databasename];Data Source=[servername];MDX Compatibility=1;Safety Options=2;MDX Missing Member Mode=Errora")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it looks like your Office Data Connection is pointing to is a SQL Server Analysis Services instance (judging by the provider being `MSOLAP.4` and the CommandType being `Cube`) so you I don't think you will be able to connect to it using an OdbcConnection or similar.

You probably need to use [ADOMD.NET](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123483.aspx) to establish a connection and run your queries. Also, it won't be SQL you're writing but probably something like a MDX query - the [Client Programming](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123477.aspx) guide should have some more specific guidance about how to do that.